# How to solve different versions of python on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, python

On ubuntu 18.04 if I run the command in terminal

```
sys.version
```

it returns:

```
3.6.9 (default, Oct  8 2020, 12:12:24) \n[GCC 8.4.0]
```

But if I run this command in jupyter notebook, first run notetook in terminal:

```
jupyter notebook
```

and in notebook:

```
import sys
print (sys.version)
```

it returns:

```
3.7.3 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar 27 2019, 23:01:00) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

I would like to know why there are two different versions of python 3? As I am trying to install `igraph` and I have managed to install it, but it is not found in jupyter notebook.

Comment: Does any of the info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40694528) help you?

Comment: "I would like to know why there are two different versions of Python 3?" - You have installed multiple Python enivornments on your system.